# ARC: How to release static variable?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, static-variables

Will `dealloc` (below) release the `NSString` pointed to by the static variable `exampleString`?

```
// ExampleClass.h

@interface ExampleClass : NSObject

@end

// ExampleClass.m

static NSString *exampleString;

@implementation ExampleClass

- (void)dealloc {
    exampleString = nil;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        exampleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"example %@", @"format"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is an odd example. Firstly, `static` as used in your code doesn’t mean storage duration but visibility (linkage) instead. Secondly, it looks like you either want class methods as opposed to instance methods, or `exampleString` should be an instance variable. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Bavarious, you're right. This is an odd example. If you point me to a better example. I'm not actually doing this. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: I’m not sure, @Matt. If the code is modified to use class methods  then there’s no need for `-dealloc`. If the code is modified to use an instance variable then ARC takes care of releasing it. Moreover, `static` doesn’t really influence the code since its function there is to limit the visibility/linkage of that variable to ExampleClass.m — memory management would be the same if `static` were removed.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, because since you did not specify an ownership qualifier, the LLVM compiler infers that `exampleString` has `__strong` ownership qualification.

This means that by setting `exampleString` to `nil` in `dealloc`, you are retaining `nil` (the new value), which does nothing, and releasing the old value.

Source

According to section [4.4.3. Template arguments](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.inference.template_arguments) of the [LLVM documentation on Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), "If a template argument for a template type parameter is an retainable object owner type that does not have an explicit ownership qualifier, it is adjusted to have `__strong` qualification."

And, according to section [4.2. Semantics](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.semanticshttp://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.semantics), "For `__strong` objects, the new pointee is first retained; second, the lvalue is loaded with primitive semantics; third, the new pointee is stored into the lvalue with primitive semantics; and finally, the old pointee is released. This is not performed atomically; external synchronization must be used to make this safe in the face of concurrent loads and stores.