# Is self.iVar necessary for strong properties with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, llvm, automatic-ref-counting

1. If I declare a property strong, like so:

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *iVar;
   ```

   When I'm setting it, does it matter if I do `iVar = ...` or `self.iVar = ...`? It seems that with ARC, they do the same thing.
2. If I only declare the instance variable (not the @property), e.g., `BOOL selected`, does that mean it's inferred to be `__unsafe_unretained` (since there's no property specifying it to be strong), or must I explicitly specify that?

It seems like I may have answered my own questions above in answering [ARC: How to release static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942041/arc-how-to-release-static-variable/7942054#7942054), but I'm still slightly confused on the above questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From a memory management perspective, using `ivar = ...` or `self.property = ...` (note: there's *no such thing* as `self.ivar`) are the same. However, using `ivar = ...` doesn't invoke the setter while `self.property = ...` does. This has 3 important ramifications, in no particular order:

1. If the property is not marked `nonatomic`, then access to the underlying ivar will not take the lock and you will be breaking the atomicity implications.
2. If the property is overridden, either by you or by a subclass, the overridden setter will not be invoked.
3. KVO notifications will not be sent.

As for only declaring the ivar, it has the same memory management semantics as declaring a local variable. This is documented in [section 4.4 of the Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.inference) document, but basically, if it's an object, it will be inferred to be `__strong`.

Comment: @kaka: No. Trivial counterexample: assigning a struct larger than a single word is almost certainly not atomic regardless of ARC/MRR.